# Would you tell me if I have used *so...that* properly?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, adverbs

Have I used *so ... that* properly in the following sentence?

> My life was so rapidly going to absurdity that I did not know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, that's a proper sentence.

Comment: Yep. Makes sense to me.